# How Do i convert array of string to Array of integer in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is there a way to convert array of strings to array of Integer in dataflow of Azure data factory

Answer (score 0):

this should do it: map(myArray,toInteger(#item))

Comment: Thanks, Mark I did try this approach looks like it returns array of "Any" type which is complaining on my sink(Postgres) side to either cast or convert

Comment: are you sure that all values inside your array can be cast to integer?